# Local rings induce vector space on module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading a claim about local rings and I came across the following:

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and $M$ is a finitely generated $R-module$  then, $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is an $R/\mathfrak{m}$ module, where for $\overline{r}\in R/\mathfrak{m}$, and $\overline{m}\in M/\mathfrak{m}M$, $\overline{r}.\overline{m} = \overline{rm}$.

I don't see why $M$ being either finitely generated or $R$ a local ring has to do with with $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ becoming an $R/\mathfrak{m}$ module. Perhaps well definedness of the operation?

Comment: @Crostul I edited.

Comment: Finite generation is unimportant to bring able consider $M/mM$ as an $R/m$-module. It's probably important for the next claim, though - Nakayama's lemma frequently takes this as a hypothesis. (When you say "I read..." it's important to say *where* you read it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M/ \mathfrak m M$ is always a $R/ \mathfrak m$-module.

The fact that $R$ is local, the fact that $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, and the fact that $M$ is finitely generated are irrelevant in this case.

For any ring $R$, any ideal $I \subseteq R$  and for any $R$-module $M$, the module $M/IM$ has a natural structure as a $R/I$-module given by
$$(r+I)\cdot (x+IM)=rx +IM$$